# Thymeleaf Form - Text Only, No Form

Tags: spring, forms, thymeleaf

I've been messing with this for over an hour and I know I'm just over looking something, so can someone please point it out to me?

I am new to Spring and I am trying to get a Thymeleaf form to work with my Spring project.

My controller:

```
public class ExampleController
{
    
    @GetMapping("/sendForm")
    public String sendForm(Model model) 
    {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "addUser";
    }

    @PostMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(User user) {

        return "showMessage";
    }
```

My user:

```
    private String name;
    private String occupation;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

All that shows on my page is just "addUser" in plain text.

Edit:
https://github.com/agrapes22/employeeTrackerApp Added full code to GitHub.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `ExampleController` annotated with `@Controller` or `@RestController` ?

Comment: I think it's @RestController, but I've tried it both ways

Comment: It should be `@Controller`. Only when using that, Spring will interpret the returned String as a view. With `@RestController` the return String is considered the response body. Are you using Spring Boot? It is a lot easier to start your project on https://start.spring.io/ (Be sure to include the _Web_ and _Thymeleaf_ dependencies).

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse plugin for spring boot and maven. I have the thymeleaf and web dependencies in my pom.xml file. And I tried it with @Controller and that still have me just a text string

Comment: Could you put your code on a github repository? There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted here.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to add it later this afternoon, I'm away from my computer at the moment. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/agrapes22/employeeTrackerApp Uploaded. Sorry for any bad formatting, uploaded quickly from where I left off last night.

Comment: Omg it works now... I literally changed it back to @Controller (which is what I had to start with) and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following example on how to create a ***form*** from this tutorial:

> This guide walks you through the process of using Spring to create and
> submit a web form.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "greeting";
  }

  @PostMapping("/greeting")
  public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    return "result";
  }

}
```

> In Spring’s approach to building web sites, HTTP requests are handled
> by a controller. These components are easily identified by the
> @Controller annotation. The GreetingController in the following
> listing handles GET requests for /greeting by returning the name of a
> View (in this case, greeting).

What it looks like to me is that since your missing @Controller annotation your method is returning string "addUser" instead of matching it with a view named "addUser" and returning the actual view.

Comment: Sorry, my controller annotation got cut off. That's the the tutorial I started with and couldn't get to work.

Comment: what is the name of your views?